# Compare (JOIN) tables and get new records

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, datatable, compare

i'm having a trouble here.. Lets say i have two tables, the only unique thing between records is their barcode. I'm using this code:

```
INSERT INTO rez1(barcode,No_,lik_pagr,inventkiekis,Vidurkis,skirias)
SELECT t2.barcode, t2.No_, t1.lik_pagr, t2.lik_pagr, ROUND(t2.lik_pagr - t1.lik_pagr,3) AS   'Vidurkis', CASE WHEN (t1.lik_pagr - t2.lik_pagr)<>0 THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END
FROM likuciai AS t1
INNER JOIN pirmoji AS t2 
ON t1.barcode = t2.barcode;
```

The problem here i have - that it only selects records that are present in in both tables (ON barcode) but how can i also get records that barcode is not equal to table t1?
Cause t2 is always user updated table and t1 is the old one and i have to show and apply the same arithmetic to those records to as on those that matches.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a LEFT JOIN. Simply replace "INNER" with "LEFT". This will get all the records from t1 and return NULL for t2 values where t1.barcode does not have a matching barcode in t2.

Comment: It hard for me to tell what i want but i need to get all records from t2 not from t1. SQLite does not have right JOIN so i have to change possitions from ON t1.barcode = t2.barcode; to ON t2.barcode = t1.barcode; and use left join ? thanks/

Comment: And how will i know which records is new ones?

Comment: @Tommix: I'd suggest going and looking up some help on Left joining. In essence though a left join says I want everything from the left hand table (ie the first one) and anything that matches in the right one (ie the second table) and null if nothign matches. Adding a where clause to say "right table field identity is null" will give you the records that are just in the left table and not in the right table. So then its just a case of putting your tables in the right place. :)

Comment: @Chris i already made good positions in my code and i'm getting new records, but i now have problem - how can i know which ones are new ones? Also how to know which records in table2 is not exists like in t1? Cause maybe someone deleted record from t2 - i have to know that too. It's kinda hard task to do it with only SQL :D PS I'm using DatagridView to display records. And BTW - where to look to know which table is left? the one that is after FROM? :D

Comment: I'm not sure how you will know what are new ones or even what you mean by new. And you may have to do a second query to find orphaned records in the other table too. The easy bit to answer is how you know which table is left. If your statement looks like `SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.x = t2.x` then t1 is the left table. Basically the left is always the one before the LEFT JOIN statement.

Comment: I think too that i'll be forced to use second and third query to identify new/deleted entries and i know how, with NOT IN. Than merge those 3 results to one table.